# Out of 2n + 1 elements in the array, there are n duplicates and one non-duplicate. Find the non-duplicate

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve a codility task. link [here](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/2-arrays/odd_occurrences_in_array/).

**The basic question goes as follows. There are `2n+1` elements in the array out of which `n` are duplicates with `1` other element which does not have a duplicate. I want to find the non-duplicate element efficiently.**

My current implementation involves sorting the array initially and comparing the side by side elements to find the non-duplicate. It is not passing 1 test case.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    Arrays.sort(A);
    int index = 0;
    if(A.length==1){
    return A[0];
    }

        if(A[0]!=A[1]){
        return A[0];
        }


    for(int i = 1;i<A.length;i++){
        if(i==A.length-1){

            index = i;
            break;
        }

        if(A[i-1]!=A[i]&&A[i]!=A[i+1]){
            index = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    return A[index];
}
}
```

I only get 80% accuracy. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You should provide the unit tests, Saugat... And your title is so generic.

Comment: I could diagnose the problems if I knew what the unit tests were. In codility they don't show what the unit tests are because the users might then brute force the code. Sorry I can't provide the unit tests since I myself don't know them.

The best thing we can do is read the question and provide a logic for solving that problems. Thanks anyways :) .

Comment: Can you come up with a unit test that fails in a similar way to the actual unit test that is failing?

Comment: In this case, which is the program specification?

Comment: @MarcelJacquesMachado can you suggest me a title? I am new to StackOverflow I am not yet used to the etiquette here.

Comment: There's a comment with a good answer on the site. Use `^`. `int r = 0; for (int i : A) { r ^= i; } return r;`

Comment: @MarcelJacquesMachado The program specification I have given in the link. The goal is to solve the problem provided. I believe the logic of my code is fine but apparently its not since it fails many of the unit tests in the server.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah I had already researched and had found the elegant solution of using XOR and solving the problem. But I also want to know how my logic is wrong and find some other way to solve the problem.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Nope I could not. I tried to come up with one but could not create a test which failed.

Comment: Sorting becomes inefficient when n = 10^6. Try using the concept of `XOR`. Remember: `a XOR a = 0`? Can you use the above logic to get the non duplicate?

Comment: @RobertColumbia: Edited the question.Please remove your vote to put on hold

Comment: @User_Targaryen you can also ping people by name with an @ sign to review. I only saw this had a high reopen count cuz of bot output. As opposed to an inbox alert

Comment: @User_Targaryen Yes this is an excellent method to solve the question, probably the best. However I want to know what the flaw in the logic of my code such that it fails some of the cases. It somehow does not work for all of the values. Currently I am not concerned with efficiency but with correctness.

Comment: `I want to know what [is] the flaw in the logic of my code such that it fails some of the cases` - do you get to know the reason for (claimed…) failure, such as _Wrong answer_, _Memory limit exceeded_, _Time limit exceeded_? (If you get none, it still may be the latter.)

Comment: @greybeard My code fails 25% of the test cases. It does not work for all of the unit tests they use. So somehow the logic of the code does not cover all of the possible inputs.

Comment: Try and comment and format the source code properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your logic, with some explanation:

```
import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
   Arrays.sort(A);
   int index = 0;
   if(A.length==1){
    return A[0];
   }
   index = A.length - 1; // if all adjacent elements are same, 
                      //then the last number has odd occurrences
   for(int i = 1;i<A.length;){
       if(A[i] != A[i-1]){
           index = i-1;
           break; // we can break as there is only one such element with odd occurrences
       }
       i = i + 2; // when adjacent alements are same, jump by 2 places
   }
   return A[index];
   }
}
```

Your code fails for an input like: `A[]` =`{1,1,1,2,2}`. The expected output should be `1`. I have included this case in your logic. The comments would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using hashMap

```
fun oddOccurrencesInArray() {
    val inputList = arrayListOf<Int>(2, 3, 2, 7, 7, 4, 3)

    if (inputList.size == 1) {
        println("Output :" + inputList[0])
        return
    }

    val hashMap = hashMapOf<Int, Int>()
    for ( (index, element) in inputList.withIndex()) {

        if (hashMap.containsKey(element)) {
            hashMap.remove(element)
        } else {
            hashMap.put(element, index)
        }

    }
    println("Output :" + hashMap.keys.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply XOR operation on all the elements with the same value canceled out and nonduplicate will remain as it is.

```
public static int getUniqueNumber(int[] arr) {
      
     int res = arr[0];

     for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
          res ^= arr[i];
     }

    return res;

}
```